# CartThrob Price Modifier - Hide form if no options available

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce, redirects

I have a channel to create an event. I also have a CartThrob Price Modifier field to add tickets if they are available.

On the single entry page, I only wish to show the exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form if the single entry has available tickets.

I'm using the following code;

```
{if event_tickets:total_results}
<div id="event_tickets" class="box toptagorange buybox">
    <h2>Buy Tickets</h2>
        {exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form
            return="shop/basket"
        }
        <fieldset>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="ticket">Ticket</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                    </tr>
                    {event_tickets}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{option_name} <span class="price">{exp:cartthrob:view_formatted_number number="{price:plus_tax}" prefix="£" decimals="2"}</span></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="quantity[{row_id}]" value="" class="tiny" /></td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_options[{row_id}][event_tickets]" value="{option_value}" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="entry_id[{row_id}]" value="{entry_id}" />
                    </tr>
                    {/event_tickets}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Buy Tickets">
    {/exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form}
</div>
{/if}
```

This works fine for an event that has tickets. However, if an event doesn't have any tickets then the page just goes to a 404. I was wondering if someone might be able to help figure this out?

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: I have resolved this by using a Matrix field instead of the CartThrob Price Modifier field. I will mark this as answered when I am able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using Matrix field type instead:

```
{if event_tickets}
<div id="event_tickets" class="box toptagorange buybox">
<h2>Buy Tickets</h2>
{exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form
return="shop/basket"
}
<fieldset>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="ticket">Ticket</th>
<th>Qty</th>
</tr>
{event_tickets}
<tr>
<td>{if option_name}{option_name}{if:else}{option_value}{/if} <span class="price">{price_plus_tax_numeric}</span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity[{row_id}]" value="" class="tiny" /></td>
<input type="hidden" name="item_options[{row_id}][event_tickets]" value="{option_value}" />
<input type="hidden" name="entry_id[{row_id}]" value="{entry_id}" />
</tr>
{/event_tickets}
</tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
{if '{event_tickets:sum col="inventory"}' == 0}
<p>Out Of Stock</p>
{if:else}
<input type="submit" value="Buy Tickets">
{/if}
{/exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form}
</div>
{/if}
```

Comment: I've moved your solution down into the "answer". This allows people to easily find it, and also allows the community to continue to submit alternative "answers" in future.